# read layout_constraintWidth_percent value from dimens.xml

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

Hi I want to read the value of

```
app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.31"
```

from xml. as you now the value should be between 0 and 1, but it only accept integer values by default:
[image]

this is my dimens.xml:

```
<resources>
<integer name="grid_cell_prec_integer">2</integer>
<fraction name="grid_cell_prec_fraction">0.31</fraction>
<item name="grid_cell_prec_float" format="float" type="dimen">0.31</item>
</resources>
```

only <<grid_cell_prec_integer>> is detected from dimens.xml as you can see in the previous image, what should I do?

Comment: Just enter `@fraction/grid_cell_prec_fraction` for the value. It is just the autocomplete that is not working.

Comment: @Cheticamp thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@Cheticamp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6287910/cheticamp) asnwered correctly:

Just enter @fraction/grid_cell_prec_fraction for the value. It is just the autocomplete that is not working